# Practical guide to the Brisker method in English?

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, torah-study, english

Is there a book that serves as a practical guide in English to applying the [Brisker method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brisker_method) of learning Gemara?

Comment: [On how many feet?](http://www.sacred-texts.com/jud/tgm/tgm11.htm)

Comment: Have you looked at the External Links section on the ref'd wikipedia page?

Comment: @DoubleAA two is fine, and thanks for the help with tagging!

Comment: @DavidPerlman I saw those links - I'm looking for a book.  Summaries are good but a thorough practical guide would be better.

Comment: See also [this](http://www.aishdas.org/rygb/derachim.htm)

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/18081/1059

Answer (score 5):

[The Brisker Derech: A Practical Guide](http://www.jewishusedbooks.com/prodview.asp?idProduct=35919) by Moshe Wachtfogel goes through practical applications of the Brisker approach.  It seems to be published by Feldheim, but I could not find it on their site.

I have not read through this work, but a cursory look inside prompted me to purchase this book for a friend.  I purchased it at a local book store.

Comment: +1 (not that I'm familiar with this book). Re "I could not find it on their site": presumably, then, it's [out of print](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-print_book).

Comment: @msh210, must have gone like hotcakes as I was shown the book by the bookstore owner about a year ago as a new book that just came out.

Comment: @YDK, Amazon's (sprase!) page on this book says Feldheim 1993, for what that's worth.

Answer (score 3):

There's a book called "Lomdus" by a Rabbi Adler, if I recall correctly.

Comment: Rabbi who Adler?

Comment: +1, this is a great book. [R' Yitzchak Adler](http://www.jewishusedbooks.com/prodview.asp?idProduct=59331)

Answer (score 2):

There's also a very nice book called *Understanding Reb Chaim* by Rabbi Yonoson Hughes (Israel, 2010). In it, the author translates and provides extensive commentary on ten of the *maamarot* from Reb Chaim's magnum opus.