# What are some sefarim that go through the Chakirot of ש״ס?

Tags: talmud-gemara

It would also help if the sefer demonstrates some foundations of the applications of those chakirot.

Comment: As in, chakiros presented in Shas itself? Or chakiros discussed by Geonim, Rishonim, and Achronim in explaining Shas? Is this already answered [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/105260/)?

Comment: Be very careful with such works. They can dangerously bias your learning.

Comment: @DoubleAA oh wow, do you mean for example, that one will always use  the chakirah when going through the sugya?

Comment: @YaakovPinchas There may be other conceptualizations which fit better or different formulations that are more insightful. When you do it yourself you can appreciate the nuances in discovery, whereas if you read one official sounding idea then it's hard to get yourself to try to think of other perspectives. It's not like publisher of some summary work has a figured out all of Torah.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Practical guide to the Brisker method in English?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18065/practical-guide-to-the-brisker-method-in-english)

Comment: ספר משמרת חיים   ספר מנחת חינוך   Mishmeret chayim is chakirot. I personally don't know it. But best short and clear chakirot in my opinion are in Minchat chinuch. I understand you want short chakirot, not an encyclopedia of chakirot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[קובץ יסודות וחקירו](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%91%D7%A5_%D7%99%D7%A1%D7%95%D7%93%D7%95%D7%AA_%D7%95%D7%97%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%AA)ת
(Koveitz Yesodos and Chakiros)

It’s a wonderful sefer that would seem to be exactly what you’re looking for

Here’s [a link to it](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=57246&pgnum=1) on HebrewBooks, or can also opt to purchase a hard copy online.

Comment: Ah yes this is precisely what I was looking for, the title seems familiar to me when it was suggested by a rebbi long ago, thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Practical guide to the Brisker method in English?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18065/21) is similar; it mentions [Rabbi Yitzchak Adler's sefer *Lomdus*](http://www.jewishusedbooks.com/prodview.asp?idProduct=59331)